# Safe way to remove a Chroot environment

Tags: 16.04, disk-usage, chroot

I created a chroot environment to test an old release without reinstalling the operating system. Now I am done with it. I would like to remove it since it has a very large footprint.

I am tempted to delete the folder in `/var/lib/schroot/` but maybe it is better to ask here.

Is there a safe way to remove it?

---

EDIT: Can't remember the exact steps I used to create it. It does not appear with the command `schroot -l`

```
userk@dopamine:$ schroot -l
chroot:indigo_trusty
chroot:ros_trusty
```

These are the ones I created a couple of months ago and they are located in `/srv/`

```
userk@dopamine:/var/lib$ ll /srv/chroot/
total 16
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 feb 17  2016 ./
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 nov  3  2015 ../
drwxr-xr-x 21 root root 4096 feb 17  2016 indigo_trusty/
drwxr-xr-x 21 root root 4096 feb 17  2016 ros_trusty/
```

The chroot I would like to safely delete is the one  in `/var/lib/`. Here is the output of `tree -L 2`

```
schroot/
├── mount
│   └── indigo_trusty-d4bb07e4-806f-4e23-83c2-5ebbfbd9054e
│       ├── bin
│       ├── boot
│       ├── dev
│       ├── etc
│       ├── home
│       ├── lib
│       ├── lib64
│       ├── media
│       ├── mnt
│       ├── opt
│       ├── proc
│       ├── root
│       ├── run
│       ├── sbin
│       ├── srv
│       ├── sys
│       ├── tmp
│       ├── usr
│       └── var
├── session
│   └── indigo_trusty-d4bb07e4-806f-4e23-83c2-5ebbfbd9054e
├── union
│   ├── overlay
│   └── underlay
└── unpack
```

Comment: Might be good to include how exactly you created it. (I'm not familiar with that stuff yet, just trying to clarify/improve the question)

Comment: Sorry, I can't remember the steps I used to create this environment. There are 3 chroots. 2 are in /srv/chroot and the one I would like to delete is in /var/lib/schroot/.  Please see my edit.